# Connecting REST Proxy to Confluent Cloud trying to connect to zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform, kafka-rest

I'm trying to connect kafka rest proxy to confluent cloud.

```
kafka-rest-start ccloud-kafka-rest.properties
```

Here is my file with properties ccloud-kafka-rest.properties

```
client.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=https
client.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
consumer.request.timeout.ms=20000
bootstrap.servers=***-****.us-east-1.aws.confluent.cloud:9092
consumer.retry.backoff.ms=500
client.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
id=kafka-rest-with-ccloud
producer.acks=1
admin.request.timeout.ms=50000
client.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="***" password="***";
```

After I run kafka-rest-start it tries connect to zookeeper (zookeeper.connect = localhost:2181).

> ERROR Server died unexpectedly:  (io.confluent.kafkarest.KafkaRestMain:63)
>   org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server 'localhost:2181' with timeout of 30000 ms

Also I tried to set zookeeper host empty, It didn't help.
How to turn off connecting to zookeeper?

Comment: please share server configurations also

Answer (score 1):

The default value for the zookeeper.connect property is localhost:2181. See [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/config.html)
You need to populate it with the address of the zookeeper of the confluent cloud.

See the instructions for connecting a rest-proxy to kafka cloud [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/cloud/connect/connect-kafka-rest-config.html)

Comment: Confluent Cloud does not expose the ZooKeeper configuration to users.
https://docs.confluent.io/current/cloud/connect/transfer-to-cloud.html#transfer-using-crep-full